# IIS6: PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, iis-6, fastcgi

I have installed PHP to work with IIS6 ([with FastCGI](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/)). I am capable of viewing a sample test website that shows the PHP info with the following code:
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Now that this works I tried to migrate my PHP website to IIS6 and here is a list of the errors/warnings I got:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(C:\WINDOWS\Temp\sess_rjbv0ialf7uf03to69q1e4l101, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in C:\Site\index.php on line 11

PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(C:\WINDOWS\Temp\sess_rjbv0ialf7uf03to69q1e4l101, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\WINDOWS\Temp) in Unknown on line 0
```

After seeing this, I corrected the php.ini file to set correctly the session save value:

```
session.save_path="C:\WINDOWS\Temp"
```

Yet doing so has done nothing! How can I make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does the account that IIS is running under (IUSER_INETPUB or whatever it is) have write permissions on C:\Windows\Temp? It may either not have permission to access anything in C:\Windows, or be explicitly denied any rights. You may want to create another directory elsewhere (C:\PHPSessions, maybe) and explicitly grant read/write (but NOT execute) permissions to the IIS account on that directory.

Comment: For some reason in Win10 PHP session creation stopped working. After checking the permissions, IIS user had read permissions, but not write permissions. Adding the write permission made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading a Windows XP development machine PHP 5.2.13.13 to 5.2.14.14, I got the same problem.

It was necessary to grant the IWAN_ account write access to any files/folders being updated by PHP e.g. *c:\windows\temp*, *C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\\cache* etc.

I guess they changed the way PHP uses worker processes.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue I had was that the performance of the server began to fail.. with errors like this for the session but the biggest issue that I saw was that mySQL was very slow..

> Sessions failing to be created
>   Mysql performance poor

What I discovered was the WPI windows program installer was installing or updating my PHP version with each new website I was creating.. this was changing the php.ini file to point to the c:\windows\temp directory

Solution was to point the sessions and all PHP operations to a phptemp directory where PHP can work outside of windows\temp

Wish I knew this a week ago.

I tried to get into the windows\temp directory to delete some files but that was not happening.. that's my next issue to address.